# Post to Facebook application page as APPLICATION user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to write a status message to my application page with the application name.

I'm using

```
$app_id = 'ID OF MY APPLICATON'
$facebook->api($app_id.'/feed', 'POST', array('message' => 'test'));
```

after the post is written my name is shown but I want instead of my name the application name to be shown, is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App pages work the same as fan pages, so you'd just do the same as if you wanted it posted by a fan page

Info here - http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/

The key is to use an access_token from the page, not the access_token of your user account

```
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
    'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```